# Error in php mysql connection using xampp

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect a HTML page using PHP form to MySQL database using Xampp. The HTML page is working fine but as soon as I press submit button a page with distinct characters appears, can anybody help with the problem?![php page][1]

HTML code:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <body bgcolor="black">
    <font color="white">

    <form action="a.php" method="post">

    <center>
    <h1><font color = "gold"><marquee>Welcome to online bus booking!!!</h1></marquee>               </font color>
    <h3> 
    First Name:<br><input type = "text" name = "fnm"><br>
    Last name:<br><input type = "text" name = "lnm"><br>
    Mobile:<br><input type = "text" name = "mob"><br> 
    Age:<br><input type = "number" name = "age"><br>
    Source:<input type = "text" name = "src">
    Destination:<input type = "text" name = "des"><br>
    <font color="orange">Passenger Address:<br></font color>
    Street:<br><input type = "text" name = "str"><br>
    Area:<br><input type = "text" name = "area"><br>
    City:<br><input type = "text" name = "cty"><br>

    <input type = "submit">

    </h3>
    </center>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP code:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdb");
    if(mysqli_connect_error())
   {
       echo "FAILED" . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
   $sql="INSERT INTO exp VALUES('$_POST[fnm]', '$_POST[lnm]', $_POST[mob], $_POST[age],        '$_POST[src]', '$_POST[des]', '$_POST[str]', '$_POST[area]', '$_POST[cty]')";
   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
   echo "1 record added";
   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: What is 'a page with distinct characters'?

Comment: @iatboy I've added the php code

Comment: @MikeW a page with "PK!Ýü•7f [Content_Types].xml ¢( ´TËnÂ0¼Wê?D¾V‰¡‡ªªú8¶H¥`ì XõKöòúûnDUA*å)YïÌììÄƒÑÚšl 1iïJÖ/z,'½ÒnV²ÉK~Ï²„Â)a¼ƒ’m ±Ñðúj0ÙHu»T²9bxà<É9X‘ ÀQ¥òÑ ¤×8ãAÈO1~ÛëÝqé‚Ãk6$N{9›êÍ+P9Y ¢†vuÇGD²ìÃï»ÆoR€”wàÍ³¶ ÌIÊŠ~‰‰˜8›ïWòZè“"V0}¿˜ûßÀ»„´ù“>þÁŒýuQwHoî·áÿÿPK!‘·óN_rels/.rels ¢( Œ’ÛJA†ïßaÈ}7Û "ÒÙÞH¡w"ë„™ìwÌ¤Ú¾½£ ºPÛ^æôçËOÖ›ƒ›Ô;§<¯aYÕ Ø›`Gßkxm·‹PYÈ[š‚g GÎ°inoÖ/<‘”¡<Œ1«¢â³†A$>"f3°" and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's way too late guys, but I solved the issue. This doesn't means it took me 3 years to solve it, I just forgot to post the answer. It was happening because I was editing the php code in Wordpad. I copied and saved the code in Notepad and the issue was solved.

Thank you for your valuable input guys.

Answer (score 3):

Here, let me correct the syntax :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO exp VALUES('".$_POST['fnm']."','".$_POST['lnm']."','".$_POST['mob']."', '".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['src']."','".$_POST['des']."','".$_POST['str']."','".$_POST['area']."', '".$_POST['cty']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is wrong : `$sql="INSERT INTO exp VALUES('$_POST[fnm]', '$_POST[lnm]', $_POST[mob], $_POST[age],        '$_POST[src]', '$_POST[des]', '$_POST[str]', '$_POST[area]', '$_POST[cty]')";`

as you are not referring `$_POST variables using their name` , *missing the quotes surrounding the variable name*. correct the line and your data should be inserting successfully.

Comment: Nope, it is showing same error page, can you be more specific with the correction?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following PHP and let us know what happens:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `exp` VALUES('{$_POST['fnm']}', '{$_POST['lnm']}',
    '{$_POST['mob']}', '{$_POST['age']}', '{$_POST['src']}', '{$_POST['des']}',
    '{$_POST['str']}', '{$_POST['area']}', '{$_POST['cty']')"
    or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
$output = $con->$sql
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Is anything different this way?

Note: To be syntactically proper you would want to explicitly state where you want the values inserted as follows:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `table_name` (`first_value`, `second_value`, `third_value`)
    VALUES ('{value1}', '{value2}', '{value3}');";
```